# Set Membership Function and uniqueness question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It's my understanding that in Set Theory, there is one unique set with elements $\{x_0,...,x_n\}$ and equality between sets is defined with the Axiom of Extensionality $\forall A \, \forall B \, ( \forall X \, (X \in A \iff X \in B) \implies A = B)$ or with subset $\forall A \, \forall B \, (A \subset B \land B \subset A) \implies A = B)$.  This seems to imply a set represented by a letter may have equality to a set of a different letter.  Given this I do not see a bijective function such that $f : S \longleftrightarrow \mathcal P(U)$ where $S$ are the letters used as arguments to $\in$.  I'm a bit confused over equality as it appears two letters of the meta-theory may represent the same set.

**Question** can I assume, as the Axiom of Extensionality suggests, there is no unique letter representing a particular set?  For instance, $p \in A, p \in B, A = B$.

**Question**(optional) if so, was there any rationale to taking this position vs unique letters per set?

Comment: You seem to ask two completely different questions, one set theory question about the axiom of extensionality, and another logical question about whether one reference can have two names. But your wording seems to mix the two questions into your first question.

Comment: Actually, there's another unrelated remark about the lack of a bijection between a set and its power set. I'm not sure how that fits in.

Comment: One and the same object can have several names. We make use of this possibility all the time, for example when we write $2+2=4$.

Comment: @Joe the bijection is where U represents the letters and the power set letters represents all member sets. The bijection means each letter representing a set has a unique set of members and there is one such set.

Comment: I'm having a hard time parsing what you wrote. I don't know what "U represents the letters" means, or what "the power set letters represents all member sets" means. If $U$ is a set, its power set is the set of all of its ***subsets***, not members. And for any set $U$, there is no bijection $f: U \to \mathcal{P}(U)$, but that has nothing to do with "names" and "references".

Comment: @AndreasBlass in your example I see equality of two expressions of symbols, but not specific to sets. I think with my example $A = B = \emptyset$ has two different symbols naming the same set.  In this case axiom of extent says they are equal, comparing every member. Like people post here, it seems this is ok. I was hoping to reduce all the comparisons by just checking the set letter vs all elements.

Comment: @Nick Think of the ingredients of my equation (the numbers 2 and 4 and the operation +) as being sets in one of the usual ways. Then the equation is about sets and its proof uses the axiom of extensionality.

Comment: @AndreasBlass so + is a set, (2,2) a set, and paired together is a set of a function application P which is a different letter then the ordinal set on RHS 4. The members are different, but these are both in equality so one can substitute one for the other.   If + is defined then the function application reduces to from P = 4 to 4 = 4, then apply Law of extent. Correct?  Are you saying P and 4 are two letters representing the same set?

Comment: "letters" are symbols of the language: we use them to "name" objects, i.e. sets

Comment: Example: the empty set and the set (call it $A$) of all and only those natural numbers that are both odd and even: $A = \{ n \in \mathbb N \mid \text {Even}(n) \text { and } \text {Odd}(n) \}$. We prove - using Extensionality - that $A = \emptyset$. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

It would not be much interesting to prove mathematical statements such that $A=A$ or $B=B$.

Proving identity statements becomes interesting when you have "two" objects that turn out to be one and the same, say " $A=B$".

For example you call $A$ the straight line segment from point $P$ to point $Q$, and you call $B$ the shortest path from $P$ to $Q$ , and you try to show that $A=B$ , that is that " the straight line from $P$ to $Q$ is also the shortest path".

Note : the mathematical technique that allows to prove this is the calculus of variations.

Here you have two names because the object is apprehended under two different concepts ( that is two different intensions as logicians say). But, in spite of the difference regarding the intensions, the two symbols turn out to have the same denotation ( they *refer* to the same object).

Note : as to the analysis of identty statements in terms of intension ( sense) and denotation , you may have a look at the *Frege* article in the *Stanford Encyclopedia Of Philosophy* ( online), section $3,2$.

Addendum :

***In a quantfied statement such as " for all A, and for all B ..." it is not assumed that A and B are two distinct objects.***

Example: let $n$ and $m$ range over the set of all real numbers except $O$

" $\text {for all $n$ and for all $m$  , if $n/m=1$ , then $n=m$}$.

Other example: let $p_1$ and $p_2$ range over the set of all human persons,

"$\text {for all $p_1$ and for all $p_2$, if $p_1=p_2$ then $ p_1 $loves $p_2$}$.

Last example :  same domain ,

$\text {for all $p_1$ and for all $p_2$, if  $ p_1 $loves $p_2$, then $p_1=p_2$}$

( In words: a person loves only herself).

Comment: In your example with the straight line using equality, I would argue that both sides of the equality reduce to the same object, the same letter, in which the equality is true. Is my thinking off?